# flink streaming create file ( csv or text) on time window

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am new to flink 
I have transformation suppose like this

```
val supportTask= customSource

  .map( line => line.split(","))
  .map( line => SupportTaskNew(line(0)toInt,line(1).toString,line(2)toString,line(3)toLong,line(4).toString,line(5)toInt,line(6)toInt))
  .filter(_ => true) //todo put sent date condition
  .map( line => Count(1))
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(20)) //todo for time being 10 seconds, actuals 30 min
 .sum(0)
```

now I want to create file for each 20 seconds time window

```
supportTask.writeAsText(("D://myfile_"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)),WriteMode.NO_OVERWRITE).setParallelism(1)
```

I have provided filename+seconds so that every time it create file with seconds appended to it.

But here only one file get created, I want to create new file for every 20 seconds window how I can do that ?

Comment: Use **DataStream.writeUsingOutputFormat() API**. **writeAsText** writes all output records to the file specified in the parameter. You have to implement a special output format to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could do this with the [Bucketing File Sink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html#bucketing-file-sink) and a custom `Bucketer`.